# What is the principle of pcap_setdirection?

Tags: c, linux, libpcap

I want to use libpcap to capture incoming Ethernet frame. But here is the problem. I use PF_PACKET and raw socket to revise the MAC header. I remove the MAC address from the header for specific implementation. I use pcap_setdirection to capture the incoming packets but get some errors I cannot understand. So I want to know how libpcap distinguish the incoming of outgoing packets? Does it judge from the MAC address or it can get directly from receiving buffer on duplex mode.
My OS is linux, CentOS 5.5. The NIC is set to promiscuous mode.

Comment: Have you looked at the source (https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap)?

Comment: I find the function static void acn_start_monitor(int fd, int snaplen, int timeout, int promiscuous, int direction). I think I will handle the direction parameter. But I cannot understand the process in this function.